# Why do interaction terms work?

Tags: regression, r, interaction, experiment-design, intuition

I am currently trying to develop a better intuition for interaction terms in linear models. And, conveniently, it turns out, if I concentrate on $\hat{y}$, it doesn't matter what kind of contrasts are applied to the factors in my model. Ie. the column space of the design matrix is the same.

Let me give a short example to clarify my point:

```r
dat <- data.frame(outcome = rnorm(n = 5),
                  age = round(rnorm(n = 5, mean = 40, sd = 5)),
                  sex = as.factor(sample(c("m", "f"), size = 5, replace = TRUE)))


dat
#>       outcome age sex
#> 1  0.68500002  35   m
#> 2 -0.96135283  33   f
#> 3  0.75994112  36   m
#> 4 -0.06326397  33   m
#> 5 -1.12973912  45   f

mm <- model.matrix(~ age + sex + age:sex, data = dat)
mm
#>   (Intercept) age sexm age:sexm
#> 1           1  35    1       35
#> 2           1  33    0        0
#> 3           1  36    1       36
#> 4           1  33    1       33
#> 5           1  45    0        0
#> attr(,"assign")
#> [1] 0 1 2 3
#> attr(,"contrasts")
#> attr(,"contrasts")$sex
#> [1] "contr.treatment"

contrasts(dat$sex) <- contr.sum(n = 2)

mm2 <- model.matrix(~ age + sex + age:sex, data = dat)
mm2
#>   (Intercept) age sex1 age:sex1
#> 1           1  35   -1      -35
#> 2           1  33    1       33
#> 3           1  36   -1      -36
#> 4           1  33   -1      -33
#> 5           1  45    1       45
#> attr(,"assign")
#> [1] 0 1 2 3
#> attr(,"contrasts")
#> attr(,"contrasts")$sex
#>   [,1]
#> f    1
#> m   -1

c(Matrix::rankMatrix(mm))
#> [1] 4

# Because the rank of the combined model matrices is also 4, 
# the column space of mm and mm2 are identical
c(Matrix::rankMatrix(cbind(mm, mm2)))
#> [1] 4

# Alternative, we can also look at \hat{y} and see that they are identical
predict(lm(dat$outcome ~ mm - 1))
#>           1           2           3           4           5 
#>  0.55677535 -0.96135283  0.84542423 -0.02052241 -1.12973912
predict(lm(dat$outcome ~ mm2 - 1))
#>           1           2           3           4           5 
#>  0.55677535 -0.96135283  0.84542423 -0.02052241 -1.12973912
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This is of course all very nice, however I wonder actually why this is the case? What specific conditions must be met for matrix $A$ and $B$ to have the same column space, where $A = [a_1\ a_2\ (a_1 \odot a_2)]$ and $B = [b_1\ b_2\ (b_1 \odot b_2)]$ and $a_i$ and $b_i$ are column vectors and $\odot$ is the inplace multiplication.

Let me give you another short example where the columns of $A$ and $B$ are very similar, however the column-space of $A$ and $B$ differs:

```r
tmp <- cbind(c(1, 4, 3, -2, 2), c(-3, 1, 1, 1, -1))
A <- cbind(tmp[,1], tmp[,2], tmp[,1] * tmp[,2])
A
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1   -3   -3
#> [2,]    4    1    4
#> [3,]    3    1    3
#> [4,]   -2    1   -2
#> [5,]    2   -1   -2

B <- cbind((A[,1] + 42), A[,2], (A[,1] + 42) * A[,2])
B
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]   43   -3 -129
#> [2,]   46    1   46
#> [3,]   45    1   45
#> [4,]   40    1   40
#> [5,]   44   -1  -44

c(Matrix::rankMatrix(A))
#> [1] 3
c(Matrix::rankMatrix(cbind(A, B)))
#> [1] 4
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Here, $B = [(a_1 + c)\ a_2\ ((a_1+c)\odot a_2)]$, however even with this seemingly innocuous change the columns space of $A$ and $B$ differ.

What I am looking for in the best case would be an intuitive (maybe geometric) explanation what is happening to the column space of a design matrix, when you add new column by multiplying two existing columns?
Alternatively, a set of rules how I can define $B$, so that $A$ and $B$ have the same column space would already be very helpful.
Thirdly, I would also be happy to see any rigorous discussion (book, blog-post, paper) about interaction terms and how to interpret their effect on the column space of the design matrix. (I have so far skimmed Venables and Ripley's Modern Applied Statistic and Christensen's Plane Answers to Complex Questions, but didn't find a satisfying explanation).

Comment: Much will become clear once you explicitly include the constant column in your model matrix and consider transformations of the form $x\to \alpha x + \beta$ and $y\to \gamma y+\delta;$ that is, independent shifts and rescalings of the original variables $x$ and $y.$

Comment: Thanks, yes I noticed that including an intercept meant that A and B in my second example have the same column-space. However, for interactions it also works for models without intercept. Is there a general rule for this? Or how would I go about developing/proofing such a rule?

Comment: I don't follow your comment because it's unclear what you're referring to with "it also works."

Comment: Sorry, with "it also works" I meant that if I define a linear model in R without an intercept `outcome ~ age + sex + age:sex - 1` the column space of the model matrix still doesn't depend on the contrast that is used for `sex`.

Comment: If by "contrast" you mean the way in which this binary categorical is numerically coded, the column spaces coincide because all such codings in use are just rescalings of each other. The column space *will* change when you use an encoding like Male=3, Female=-1. To see that, here's a pair of such matrices: `X<-lapply(list(A=c(-1,3),B=c(0,1)), function(sex)  model.matrix(~age*sex-1,expand.grid(age=1:3,sex=sex)))`. The space generated by all columns has 4 dimensions, not 3 (`qr(cbind(X$A, X$B))$rank`), showing the column spaces differ.

Comment: Oh, good point. I missed that. I had a second categorical value in my matrix `X<-lapply(list(A=c(-1,1),B=c(0,1)), function(sex)  model.matrix(~cat + age*sex-1,expand.grid(cat = c("a", "b"), age=1:3,sex=sex)))` which, I guess, acted like an intercept.

Comment: So, the answer would be: If each column $b_i = s_i * a_i$, the column space of A and B is the same. Or if A has a constant column $c_0$, then the each column $b_i$ can also be $b_i = s_i * a_i + s_0 * c_0$ without changing the column space.

Comment: That's right. Generally, the space generated by columns $1,$ $x,$ $y,$ and $xy$ is the same as that generated by $1,$ $u,$ $v,$ and $uv$ where $u=\alpha x+\beta,$ $v=\gamma y+\delta,$ because $$uv=(\alpha x+\beta)(\gamma y+\delta)=(\beta\delta)1+(\alpha\delta)x+(\beta\gamma)y+(\alpha\gamma)xy$$ is explicitly a nontrivial linear combination of $1,$  $x,$ $y,$ and $xy$ provided $\alpha\gamma\ne0.$

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me understand :)
If you turn the comments into an answer, I will accept it. However, I guess you don't really _need_ the points :)